# Read a file with Rust WASM

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, yew, rust-wasm

I am trying to read a file called Book.txt within my Rust yew app. I am serving Book.txt using trunk's `copy-file` so that it is accessible from http://localhost:8080/Book.txt.
Trying to read the file using std::fs did not work (with error `Could not open file: Error { kind: Unsupported, message: "operation not supported on this platform" }`), but I'm wondering if there is some other way to read this file.
I tried to also use the `wasm32-unknown-emscripten` target but that didn't seem to do anything. I would really like to avoid if at all possible having a client-server architecture for this where I have the file on the server and read it there as I would like to eventually host this all on github pages.

Help is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot read files within WebAssembly, just like within JavaScript. You have to read them within the server and send it to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `std::fs` accesses the local filesystem. In case of a web app, the local platform is the browser. There is no file system in the browser, so there is nothing to access, hence it fails with the error message you showed.

  - Emscripten actually emulates a local in-memory filesystem in the browser, and there should be some way of pre-seeding that filesystem with files. But I have no idea how to do that in Rust, and in general, it doesn't hold much benefit over the next option:
- The easiest way for you to have the content of the file would be to use `std::include_str!`. But that will include the content in the compiled output, which may not be what you want if `Book.txt` is huge and not always needed, or if you want to change it after you finish compiling.
- Since you are already serving `Book.txt` via http, you should be able to request it through XHR, either using "raw" APIs like `web_sys::Window::fetch_with_request_and_init`, or through some convenience crate like `reqwest`. (If that doesn't work, make sure you're not running into CORS limitations.)

Comment: "way of pre-seeding that filesystem with files" you can do that, but you already have to have it in memory, so there isn't really any point unless you want to persist that data across refreshes.

Comment: @JaredSmith I was thinking of https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/files/packaging_files.html#packaging-files Not sure why there's no point, it does make a file from the build directory available through the file system at runtime.

Comment: @Caesar actually I kinda take it back. What I meant by that was that all of the data/code has to be shipped over the wire, and to use something it has to be in memory. So in my mind there really isn't a perf win there and the case for pre-packing is where you are *porting* an existing program to WASM that expects a certain file/directory structure to exist and it's easier to create it than to modify the program. But after reading the link and thinking about it some more it makes more sense than I gave it credit for: You don't want the *parser* to have to deal with e.g. MB-sized game assets.